# Translating string to another lang using array

Tags: php

I want to translate all the keys from the array that occur in this string:

```
$bar = "It gonna be tornado tomorrow and snow today.";
```

and replacing it with the value using this array:

```
 $arr = array(
   "tornado" => "kasırga",
   "snow" => "kar"
);
```

So the output will be:

```
$bar = "It gonna be kasırga tomorrow and kar today.";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is called string-translate, written in it's short form as [`strtr`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/strtr):

```
$bar = strtr($bar, $arr);
```

Contrary to the popular belief in the other answers, `str_replace` is *not* safe to use as it re-replaces strings which is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation. This is now stuck on my head :) Thanks to others too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `str_replace` function:

```
$tmp = str_replace(array_keys($arr), array_values($arr), $bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
    $bar = str_ireplace($key, $value, $bar);
}
```